# what is difference between primary and unique key?

Tags: database, foreign-keys, primary-key, rdbms, unique-key

What is the difference between Primary and Unique key (in MySQL)? How these can be considered as a foreign key? please explain.
I tried creating a database table and don't know how to make a primary key as a  foreign key. Does it take Joins concept where the separating attribute automatically create a foreign key?

Comment: Please ask one question per post. (Obviously--) These are faqs. Before considering posting please always google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS This is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A table in MySQL can only have one Primary Key at most, while you can create as many unique Keys or indexes as you want.

Also a primary key is not nullable while a unique key can have NULL as value.

But the biggest difference is the purpose:

You want to have a **primary key** because you need an identifier

The **unique Key/Index** on the other hand is usefull to controll values that are automatically getting inserted into your table (e.g. to avoid duplicates where none are allowed)

If you want to use a column as a forgein key, you need to define it as a primary key first. Unique Constraint can not be related with other tables as a foreign key.